# an efficient way to speed up some numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find an efficient code instead of the following piece of code (that is only one part of my code), to increase the speed:

```
for pr in some_list:
    Tp = T[partition[pr]].sum(0)
    Tpx = np.dot(Tp, xhat)
    hp = h[partition[[pr]].sum(0)
    up = (uk[partition[pr][:]].sum(0))/len(partition[pr])
    hpu = hpu + np.dot(hp.T, up)
    Tpu = Tpu + np.dot(Tp.T, up)
```

I have at least two more similar blocks of code. As you can see, I used fancy indexing three times (really couldn't find another way). In my algorithm, I need this part to be done very quickly, but it's not happening now. I will really appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you all.

Best,

Comment: An obvious, though maybe minor step is to assign `ppr=partition[pr]` once , instead of repeating that indexing 3 more times.  But we also need to know something about the variables - which are arrays, which lists, what is shape, dtype, etc.  Why the `[:]`?

Comment: T is an array of size (1000, 30, 100). Tp is an array that is built by adding up rows of T that is specified by partition. Partition is a list of lists. xhat is any array of size (100,1). h is an array of size (1000, 30, 1). uk is an array of size (1000, 30, 1)

Comment: And the `partition` sublists can differ in length?  That makes it difficult to replace the iteration with one set of array operations.

Comment: yes, in each iterations, the size of the partition sublists, as well as the size of partition itself, changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your partitions are few and have many elements each, you should consider swapping around the indices of your objects. Summing an array of shape `(30,1000)` along its second dimension should be faster than summing an array of shape `(1000,30)` along its first dimension, since in the former case you are always summing contiguous blocks of memory (i.e. `arr[k,:]` for each `k`) for each remaining index. So if you put the summation index last (and get rid of some trailing singleton dimension while you're at it), you might get speed-up.

As [hpaulj noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257306/an-efficient-way-to-speed-up-some-numpy-operations#comment63936434_38257306), it's not clear how your loop could be vectorized. However, since it's performance-critical, you could still try vectorizing *some* of the work.

I suggest that you store `hp`, `up` and `Tp` for each partition (following pre-allocation), then perform the scalar/matrix products in a single vectorized step. Also note that `Tpx` is unused in your example, so I omitted it here (whatever you're doing with it, you can do it similarly to the other examples):

```
part_len = len(some_list) # number of partitions, N
Tpshape = (part_len,) + T.shape[1:] # (N,30,100) if T was (1000,30,100)
hpshape = (part_len,) + h.shape[1:] # (N,30,1) if h was (1000,30,1)
upshape = (part_len,) + uk.shape[1:] # (N,30,1) if uk was (1000,30,1)
Tp = np.zeros(Tpshape)
hp = np.zeros(hpshape)
up = np.zeros(upshape)

for ipr,pr in enumerate(some_list):
    Tp[ipr,:,:] = T[partition[pr]].sum(0)
    hp[ipr,:,:] = h[partition[[pr]].sum(0)
    up[ipr,:,:] = uk[partition[pr]].sum(0)/len(partition[pr])

# compute vectorized dot products:
#Tpx unclear in original, omitted
# sum over second index (dot), sum over first index (sum in loop)
hpu = np.einsum('abc,abd->cd',hp,up)  # shape (1,1)
Tpu = np.einsum('abc,abd->cd',Tp,up)  # shape (100,1)
```

Clearly the key player is [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). And of course if `hpu` and `Tpu` had some prior values before the loop, you have to increment those values with the results from `einsum` above.

As for `einsum`, it performs summations and contractions of arrays of arbitrary dimensions. The pattern apearing above, `'abc,abd->cd'`, when applied to 3d arrays `A` and `B`, will return a 2d array `C`, with the following definition (math pseudocode):

```
C(c,d) = sum_a sum_b A(a,b,c)*B(a,b,d)
```

For a given fix `a` summation index, what's inside is

```
sum_b A(a,b,c)*B(a,b,d)
```

which, if the `c` and `d` indices are kept, will be euqivalent to `np.dot(A(a,:,:).T,B(a,:,:))`. Since we're summing these matrices with respect to `a` too, we're supposed to do exactly what your loopy version does, adding up each `np.dot()` contribution of the total sums.

Comment: Thank you so  much for you suggestion. I am changing my code based on what you suggested. The only problem is, I am having really hard time to understand how einsum works.

Comment: @Bob.S.P I updated the answer with some explanation, let me know if that helps. Also, make sure that it actually returns the same result, it's easy to slip up with these vectorized calculations:)